# How to convert For Loop results into an Array then count the integers of the resulting Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, console.writeline

In C#, how would I go about converting the result of a For Loop into an Array and count (Display on the Console) the number of integers stored in that converted array?

Please see below for what I have thus far:

```
  for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
```

And feel free to let me know if there is a different way to count the results of the code I have above.
Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You question is unclear: what do you mean by "result of a for loop", what is that "converted array"? Please write down the expected result.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Linq ?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am still a beginner. I guess I was thinking that if the results of my For loop written to the the console showed [7,3,5,6,8,9], is there a way to have the console show a count of 6 instead?

Comment: Yes, @JHBonarius, I am allowed to use Linq. I'm just not sure how I would implement it.

Comment: And if you want the amount of numbers divisable by 3 between 1 and 100, just 100/3 and round down.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: _"[7,3,5,6,8,9]"_ wait what? The code you show doesn't do that.

Comment: That is a good point, I could do 100/3 and round down. I was just wondering if there was another way of completing the same thing using a For Loop. In the process of practicing the use of For Loops.

Comment: @JHBonarius, sorry for any confusion. The statement of "[7,3,5,6,8,9]" was an example outside the result of what my code result actually is. I just didn't want to make my comment to long with the result of my actual code.

Comment: Use linq, cast your array tolist() then simply convert to anything you may like

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you're after. You can use a for-loop as you've done and accomplish it like so:

```cs
var list = new List<int>();
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 != 0)
        continue;
    
    list.Add(i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    sum += i;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Count: {list.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
```

You could also accomplish this with Linq:

```cs
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 99)
    .Where(i => i % 3 == 0)
    .ToList();
var sum = numbers.Sum();

numbers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {numbers.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use List for that purpose:

```
 var list = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
 {
     if (i % 3 == 0)
     {
         list.Add(i);
         Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        myList.Add(i);                    
    }
}
        
Console.WriteLine(myList.Count);

//if you want an array....
int[] myArray;
myArray = myList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to insert the numbers into a collection to count them. Just use a variable as counter

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        count++; // Increments count by 1.
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("The count is " + count);
```